# Link to external excel file not working when the linked file is not open

Tags: excel, vba

I have made 2 small vba codes to get a file that is in a certain folder using vba. I need to write a vba code because the path where the referenced file exists changes based on the username. The data is extracted from the cells of the referenced file only when the file is left open when the referenced file is closed then I get an error "#VALUE". Can someone explain to be why this is happening.
the Vba code is not the problem, please see the codes below. Formula in a cell looks like
TXT2RNG(source_file("a5";"Line Sheet";"1607508-GEN-0047.xlsm"))

```
Public Function source_file(Optional ByVal rekke As String = "", _
             Optional ByVal arknavn As String = "Line Sheet", _
             Optional ByVal boknavn As String = "1607508-GEN-0047.xlsm")
   Dim str As String
   source_file = "'C:\BC-WorkSpace\" & UCase(Environ$("UserName")) _
& "\M-Ocd-for-meri2,D-IKM-01\Projects\1607508 BALDER FUTURE PROJECT – DETAIL DESIGN\Generic\Admin\[" & boknavn & "]" & _
   arknavn & "'!" & rekke
End Function

Public Function TXT2RNG(text) As Variant

    Set TXT2RNG = Range(text)

End Function
```

Comment: Is the behavior the same if you just paste `='C:\BC-WorkSpace\user_name\M-Ocd-for-meri2,D-IKM-01\Projects\1607508 BALDER FUTURE PROJECT – DETAIL DESIGN\Generic\Admin\[1607508-GEN-0047.xlsm]Line Sheet'!a5` into a cell?

Comment: It looks that VBA is not able to evaluate a reference to a closed workbook cell...

Comment: Add code to open the reference file if it's not already open.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld. Yes, when I copy the link into a cell directly then it works... but that is not what i want ...

Comment: @FaneDuru true, mind boggling that it can't evaluate... but when I copy paste the link directly then it seems to work but when I use th efunction source_file() it seems not to work

Comment: @RonRosenfeld everything works perfectly when the referenced files are opened and F9 is pressed. So i believe that there is something that is not active when the referenced files are closed. Please note that the path to the referenced file contains the complete address to the file location and cell

Comment: In that case, I believe, as you do, that the problem lies with VBA (not your code). There are methods, using VBA, to read data from a closed workbook. A common one in the past was to use `ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)` where `arg` is the full pathname to a cell (in R1C1) notation. It seems be limited in that it can only return a single cell, and doesn't work with `.xlsb` files.  You could also use ADO or other query methods (provided the range is named); or you could just open the workbook and then close it.